# How to order by, a json_object in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, arrays, json, aggregate-functions

I've a problem sorting a JSON_OBJECT:

[image]

How can I sort the objects as they are in the JSON OBJECT?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to control the order of the json objects within the array created by `json_arrayagg()`?

Comment: Yes, the same order of JSON_ARRAYAGG

Comment: I would also consider whether you really need a view at all

Answer (score 12):

You can't control the order of the elements in the array that `json_arrayagg()` generates, even in MySQL 8.0, as [explained in the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg):

> Aggregates a result set as a single JSON array whose elements consist of the rows. **The order of elements in this array is undefined.**

An ugly and not scalable work around is to use `group_concat()` to manually generate the json array:

```
select 
    dashboard,
    widget,
    ...
    concat(
        '[',
        group_concat(
            json_object('color_mode', color_mode, ...)
            order by <your_ordering_clumn>
        ),
        ']'
    ) js_array
from datadog_wigets_markers 
group by dashboard, widget, ...
```

This will fail on long json strings. I would rather try and live with `json_arrayagg()` and unordered arrays.

Side note: you should enumerate all the non-aggregated columns in the `group by` clause; it's a requirement in most databases, and a good coding practice.

Comment: Has this changed? The [documentation for `json_arrayagg` refers to an "over clause"](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg), but I can't get it to work.

Comment: @Bergi: the `over()` clause lets you use `json_array_agg()` as a window function - but you still don't control the order of the array elements...

Comment: I thought `over` clauses could contain `order` clauses… But apparently this part doesn't work, yes.

Comment: @Bergi: it has an `order by` clause that applies to the window itself, not the values that are being aggregated...

Comment: I agree that this is a bit ugly, but why is it not scalable? So far this is the only solution I've been able to find and I'm tempted to use it in production. Why does it fail on long json strings when json_arrayagg() does not?

Comment: @Macoshark: `group_concat()` has a default limitation of 1000 characters on the generated string (which, of course, you can increase manually). Also, this option is likely to be less efficient than a built-in (that’s two function calls instead of one). Alas, that’s the only available option as of now. It’s a pity that MySQL doesn’t provide such ordering option, while the JSON spec does specify that the ordering of elements in an array *is* meaningful.

Comment: Thank you for this.  Just wanted to add that you can `(cast concat(... ) as json)` to put this back into a json type if needed.

Comment: a new link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg

Answer (score 8):

@Gordon Linoff's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63252941/how-is-it-possible-to-order-the-array-returned-by-json-arrayagg-in-mysql) worked for me on MySQL 8.0, but I didn't test it for scalability.

As written in @Simas Jonelinuas's comment, here is the answer from the post in case the link ever becomes invalid.

```sql
SELECT A, json_arrayagg(json_obj('X',value1, 'Y',value2)) AS RESULT
FROM (SELECT . . .,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value2) as seqnum
      FROM . . . 
      . . . 
     ) x
GROUP BY A;
```

Quote: "The ROW_NUMBER() -- apparently -- manages to order the result set, even though ORDER BY does not work."

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30799906)

Comment: That was weird, but it worked.

Answer (score -3):

As workaround, instead:

```sql
select json_arrayagg(...) from someTable order by ...
```

You can:

```sql
select json_arrayagg(...) from (select someFields from someTable order by ...) as t1
```

Comment: Nope. That does NOT work. That was what I originally had. 
[BloodhunterD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70680949/2730233)'s answer works.