# How is it possible to order the array returned by json_arrayagg() in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, sql-order-by, aggregate

I want to order the array returned by json_arrayagg().
My query is similar to this:-

```
select A, json_arrayagg(json_obj('X',value1, 'Y',value2)) AS RESULT
FROM (derived table)
GROUP BY A.
```

What I want is that I want the array that returns to be ordered by value2.
I have tried adding order by clause at the end (like, order by value2: it is not working)

have tried adding order by inside json_arrayagg()..(like: json_arrayagg(json_obj() order by value2) It is not working.

Have tried using group_concat , but it is not reliable and don't know why it's not returning correct data. Have checked limits.

Please suggest me how to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, Can you please help here!

Comment: . . Unfortunately, MySQL does not formally support that functionality -- even with an `ORDER BY` in the subquery.  There is a hacky solution but no guarantee that that works.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, There was no shortcut to do it, so I tried to pass the ordered values from the required derived table to the JSON_ARRAYAGG.

But still, I would like to know the hacky solution ~ Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Apparently, there is a hack which might work:

```
SELECT A, json_arrayagg(json_obj('X',value1, 'Y',value2)) AS RESULT
FROM (SELECT . . .,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY value2) as seqnum
      FROM . . . 
      . . . 
     ) x
GROUP BY A;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` -- apparently -- manages to order the result set, even though `ORDER BY` does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Im facing the same problem, in the end i use GROUP_CONCAT instead:

```
select 
    A, 
    CONCAT('[',
      GROUP_CONCAT(JSON_OBJECT('X',value1, 'Y',value2) ORDER BY value0)
    ,']') AS RESULT
FROM (derived table)
GROUP BY A.
```